# IOError: [Errno 13] when specifying path for functions

Tags: python, path, ioerror

I am making a search engine and I need some help clearing the code where I choose a folder for searching.

I make the user specify a path with this function:

```
def location_specify():
    location = raw_input('Define path for search: ')
    return location

location = location_specify()
```

This location I use for the following function where I want to open the documents in the folder and tokenize.

```
def open_doc(location):
    docfile = codecs.open(location, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    doclist = docfile.read().lower().split()
    docfile.close()
    return doclist
```

I tested this function with this path:

```
C:\\Users\\Vestergaard\\Desktop\\Informationssoegning\\Ernaeringskorpus
```

and I receive this errormessage

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    open_doc(location)
    File "<pyshell#15>", line 2, in open_doc
    docfile = codecs.open(location, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 884, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Vestergaard\\Desktop\\Informationssoegning\\Ernaeringskorpus'
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe my functions are way off?

Comment: In the error message, `Desktop` has a space after it...

Comment: I see that now, but that must've happened as copied the error message into this post. Nicely spotted, but that's not it. - removed the space.

Comment: Is the listed path a directory, or a file?

Comment: @JohnGordon The path is a directory. The intention is to specify a directory for the function to do its thing and open the different files one by one.

Comment: `codecs.open()` is intended to be used with a file, not a directory.  If you want to open all the files in a directory, call `os.listdir()` and then pass each individual filename to `codecs.open()`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry to say, but I don't know how to do that. Is it possible to do that inside the function and make it repeat itself for each individual filename? @JohnGordon

Comment: That depends how you want your `open_doc` function to work.  Should it return a list of codecs, or just one?  If it returns a list, the calling function will need some way of knowing which codec is which.  If it returns just one, then the calling function will have to read the directory contents and call `open_doc` once for each file.

Comment: What I need from this function (and I may be way off with the code I have already) is actually a list of dictionaries with the filenames as keys and lists of words from each text as values. @JohnGordon

Comment: Do you really need a list of dictionaries?  A single dictionary can hold lots of items.  In any case, see my answer below.

Comment: Also, why are you using `codecs.open`?  If you're just grabbing text out of a file, wouldn't plain `open` work?

Comment: I guess so; truth be told, a friend helped me with this and she used `codecs.open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import codecs, os

def open_doc(directory):
    allfiles = {}
    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
        docfile = codecs.open(os.path.join(directory, filename), 'r', encoding='utf-8')
        content = docfile.read().lower().split()
        docfile.close()
        allfiles[filename] = content
    return allfiles
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried this and I get a new error message this time saying my file doesn't exist (which it really does..) 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
    open_doc(directory)
  File "<pyshell#50>", line 4, in open_doc
    docfile = codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py", line 884, in open
    file = __builtin__.open(filename, mode, buffering)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ernaering04.txt'`

apparently, it can see the file 'ernaering04.txt' but it still says, it doesn't exist..

Comment: The `open()` call needs the full pathname to the file, not just the bare filename.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Man, that is beautiful. Sorry to bother you, but there is still some sort of problem which lies in the `encoding = 'utf-8'` part. At least that is what I can deduce from the errormessage. When I test it with just `open` instead of `codecs.open` I get the dictionary as wanted (and thanks a lot for that)
I just need to have the encoding because my files are in Danish and we have the characters æ,ø and å, which otherwise just show op as random assortments of characters..

Comment: So you're not seeing the Danish special letters when you use `encoding='utf-8'`?  Are you sure that's the right encoding?  utf-8 is a popular encoding but it's not the only one.  How were the text files created?

Comment: No, sir. I am quite sure that's the right encoding as my classmates use the same one.. I actually don't know how the text files were created but they consist of just plain text with some symbols. I receive this error message: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 91: invalid start byte`

Comment: That error strongly suggests you're not using the right encoding.  Are you using `utf-8` or `utf8`?  I don't know if there is any real difference, but I've always used `utf-8`.  You might want to ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Aye, that seems to be the problem. Just for the heck of it, I tried using utf8 instead of utf-8. No difference.. I might have to ask elsewhere, but thanks a lot for all of your help!